# Why do east Pacific cyclones/hurricanes die out?

Tags: tropical-cyclone

In the Atlantic basin, tropical cyclones start in the east and move west until they either reach land or move north into cooler waters.

Based on [this map of historic paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_cyclogenesis#/media/File:Global_tropical_cyclone_tracks-edit2.jpg), there is a lot of cyclogensis in the east Pacific.  However, these paths all end before cyclones reach land, and they also don't curve northward into cooler waters as much as cyclones in the Atlantic basin.  So how do they die out?  Moreover, why don't cyclones form in warm parts of the central Pacific?

Comment: Regarding the second part of the question: the Pacific is not so warm near the southern tropic because of the Humboldt current: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humboldt_Current

Comment: @AmadouKone https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-do-hurricanes-hit-the-east-coast-of-the-u-s-but-never-the-west-coast/